# It seems no way rotate screen display after updating to Monterey, even when I press Command and Option?

Tags: macos, settings

Before updating to Monterey, I was able to turn on the Rotate Screen option by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> and clicking Display Settings, but it seems that all this doesn't work after Monterey?

Comment: Same here. MacBook Air M1 running MacOS 12.3.1. Googling didn't help. Will keep an eye on updates.

Comment: @Dabier Please Check [this method](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/qiopv1/rotate_screen_option_missing_in_monterey/). Use ⌥ twice instead of ⌘⌥.